# How to get only one of the rows that are different?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a **newsletter php module** that has a **queue list** (so my cron file can send it a specific number of emails by minute), and i wan't to show in backoffice if the newsletter has emails on queue and how many, so to save processing time, i don't wan't to get each newsletter and go field by field if it has emails to send.

So, imagine this structure in **NEWSLETTER_QUEUE** table:

```
NEWSLETTER_ID   EMAIL
1           test1@hotmail.com
1           test2@hotmail.com
1           test3@hotmail.com
1           test4@hotmail.com
2           test2@hotmail.com
2           test3@hotmail.com
2           test4@hotmail.com
3           test4@hotmail.com
```

I only wan't to get the values:

```
NEWSLETTER_ID   COUNT(EMAIL)
1               4
2               3
3               1
```

So, normally i would query newsletter by newsletter and check if it is sends pending and count, but i wan't to save processing time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT newsletter_id, COUNT(email)
FROM newsletter_queue 
GROUP BY newsletter_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT NEWSLETTER_ID,COUNT(EMAIL) FROM NEWSLETTER_QUEUE GROUP BY NEWSLETTER_ID
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1):

A simple group by should do it?

```
select
  NEWSLETTER_ID,
  COUNT(1) as [COUNT(EMAIL)]
from
  NEWSLETTER_QUEUE 
group by
  NEWSLETTER_ID
```